# How to subset geopandas dataframe based upon coordinates of points?

Tags: python, pandas, shapely, geopandas

I would like to subset a geopandas dataframe based upon values of the first coordinate of a column of points (i.e. the x values).

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame([Point((0,0)), Point((4,2)),Point((2,4))])
gdf.columns = ['points']
```

So, given the above data, I would like to check if the first coordinate is greater than 3 (for instance) so this would return an array of `[False, True, False]` so that I can then subset the original dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the x coordinate is greater than 3 you can use `apply` to extract the coordinate from the points:

```
gdf[gdf.points.apply(lambda p: p.x) > 3]
```